How do you get the contents of a nuget package to auto deploy to the output folder of a project that is referencing it
I have a nuget package that I've built and uploaded to our Nuget repository.  In it are 2 native dlls.  One for 32-bit and one for 64-bit.  I'll be referencing them in various projects (net472, net6, and .netstandard2.0). When I add them via the package manager, it simply downloads them to the Nuget cache and that's it.  I suppose that makes sense because they are native libraries and not .NET libraries so nothing would depended on them directly.  They are found and loaded explicitly at runtime however.  I would like both of these Dlls to be placed in the output folder of the referencing project in a folder named DllHome/. It is very difficult to google for this answer because the search terms are so common, and I get results for everything BUT what I'm looking for.  The .nuspec file for my package is below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyDLLs</id>
    <title>MyDLLs</title>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>author</authors>
    <tags>MyDLLs</tags>
    <description>My DLLs</description>
    <repository type="git" url="https://github.com/myrepo/nuget"/>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
     <file src="Release/MyDLL32.dll" target="runtimes/win-x86/native"/>
     <file src="Release/MyDLL64.dll" target="runtimes/win-x64/native"/>   
  </files>
</package>

I've seen something similar to what I want with a SQLite package.  The .NET package brought in some native dlls and automatically deployed them to my output folder in x86/ and x64/ folders respectively when I built.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-files-in-net-packages
